# Python:Scrapy: Error in JSON

Tags: python, json, scrapy

```
    import logging
logging.getLogger('scrapy').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
import scrapy

class spider1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Wikipedia'
    start_urls = ['https://en.Wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_(electricity)']

    def parse(self,response):
        def parse(self, response):
            for e in response.css('div#mw-content-text>div>p'):
                yield { 'para' : ''.join(e.css('::text').extract()).strip() }
```

When I'm executing it through cmd:

> scrapy runspider spider3.py -o joe.json

I'm geeting a json file of 0kbs. I can open it tho and cant find any output

Comment: Your parse method does not return anything. It just creates an inner function also called parse, which is never called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete one of string with "def parse(self,response):".